# Program does not work (compile problems)

Tags: c, string

Hello I have a small problem during compilation.

So that problem in my program are:

1. brackets(str1);  -  Too few arguments to function call
2. void brackets(str,len)  -  Conflicting types for 'brackets'

Ny code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void brackets(char str[], int len);

int main()
{
char str[99];
int len;

printf("enter Mathematical exercise: \n");
gets(str);

len = srtlen(str);

brackets(str1);
return(0);
}

void brackets(str,len)
{
char str1[99];
int i,j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == '(')
    {
        i++;
        while(str[i] != ')')
        {
            str1[j] = str[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%s\n",str1);
 }
```

I love to know what these errors arise and how can I arrange this program will work. Thanks

Comment: The clue is really in the error messages.....

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
void brackets(str,len)
```

to

```
void brackets(char str[], int len)
```

and your function call should be `brackets(str, len);`. And also change

```
len = srtlen(str); // Spelling mistake.
```

to

```
len = strlen(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

your function brackets needs two parameters, so you need to give him two:

brackets(str1);

has to become

brackets(str1, len);

Comment: combine my answer with that of haccks :)

Answer (score 0):

**You're defining the brackets function as taking 2 arguments but passing only one**. Pass the second one as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your second error, if you don't provide a type for the function parameters the compiler will assume it's of type `int`. As the first parameter have already been declared to be of type `char []` there is a mismatch between the declaration (prototype) and the definition of the function.

As for the first error, when you declare a function to take N parameters, you need to call it with N arguments. The exception being functions declare to take a [variable number of arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue: `brackets(str1);`

You called `brackets` with just one parameter, yet you define it as this:

```
void brackets(char str[], int len);
```

You need to pass an int as a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

multiple error seems in your code

Starting from `main`

you not declared `str1` in main but used it in `brackets(str1);`.i think you mean it by `str` because you declared it `char str[99];`

so make change by `brackets(str);`

Also `void brackets(str[], len)` function not specify data type of function argument please change it to `void brackets(char str[], int len)`

Also in main `len = srtlen(str);` the `srtlen` is not valid but make it `len = strlen(str);`

And last you call `brackets(str1);` but `brackets` expect two argument so please make change in main by `brackets(str,len);`

After above change your code is now clean without error as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void brackets(char str[], int len);

int main()
{
    char str[99];
    int len;

    printf("enter Mathematical exercise: \n");
    gets(str);

    len = strlen(str);

    brackets(str,len);
    return(0);
}

void brackets(char str[],int len)
{
    char str1[99];
    int i,j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '(')
        {
            i++;
            while(str[i] != ')')
            {
                str1[j] = str[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",str1);
 }
```